# WCF RoutingService failing when mex gets too large

Tags: wcf

I'm having an issue with a net.tcp WCF windows service int .NET 4.0 where it looks like my mex for a particular endpoint is too large. There is no problem at all connecting directly to the endpoint. I created a WCF RoutingService to allow someone outside our private network to connect to my internal WCF service. Getting the mex information through the RoutingService fails.

My WCF service has about 7 endpoints, and the WCF RoutingService is routing all of them, but only the large one (with 17 methods) is having the problem.

I found this link below which explains how to fix the problem when failing to connect directly to the mex endpoint

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2009/05/07/too-many-operations-or-methods-in-wcf-service-causes-the-metadataexchange-fail.aspx

But it talks about creating an endpoint in svcutil.exe.config with a contract of IMetadataExchange. The RoutingService endpoint I'm having a problem with is using the contract System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter, so I don't know if I need to configure the svcutil.exe.config file slightly differently. I've tried all sorts of combinations but couldn't get anything to work. I'm not even sure where I need to put the svcutil.exe.config file for the RoutingService WCF service to pick it up, or even if it needs one.

Does anybody know of a better solution, or a link which might provide help for when a RoutingService is involved?